# Not able to extract exact phrase from the sentence in R

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to extract exact phrase from the sentences in R. It is also extracting the sentence where its is partial matching. Example:

```
  phrase <- c("r is not working","roster is not working")
  sentence <- c("ABC is not working and roster is not working","CDE is working but printer is not working")

  extract <- sapply(phrase, grepl, x = sentence)
  extract
```

It gives the output as:

```
              r is not working      roster is not working
  [1,]             TRUE                  TRUE
  [2,]             TRUE                 FALSE
```

My desired output is:

```
              r is not working      roster is not working
  [1,]               FALSE                  TRUE
  [2,]               FALSE                  FALSE
```

phrase "r is not working" should not match with both sentences. Is there any way to deal with this. Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe add word boundaries, as in `sapply(paste0("\\b", phrase, "\\b"), grepl, x = sentence)`

Comment: "r is not working" does match both strings but adding a space before the r:  " r is not working" will prevent the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` evaluates regular expressions.

If you want to stick with those, **anchor** your search patterns to the start and end of string:

```
phrase <- c("^r is not working$", "^roster is not working$")
```

If you instead want to check for exact matches, simply use

```
extract <- sapply(sentence, `%in%`, phrase)
```